Type narrowing for object key and value generic arguments (narrowing doesn't work)
I'm trying to understand what's wrong in this code and why TypeScript doesn't narrow type for 'value' argument.
function foo<T>(data: T, cb: (key: keyof T, value: T[typeof key]) => void): void {}

foo(
  {
    a: true,
    b: 'abc',
  },
  (key, value) => {
    switch (key) {
      case 'a':
        key; // <= "a"
        value; // <= string | boolean
               // but I expect boolean here
    }
  },
);

You can see that type guard for 'key' variable works perfectly but 'value' still remains non-narrowed. Can I make 'value' type based on 'key' type?
For example:
if (key === 'b') {
  value; // <= string
}

It looks like simple logic and nothing complex. Is it possible with current TypeScript?
TS version 5.6.2.
I have tried many combinations of generics and their inheritance. Nothing works and looks like TypeScript just can't do this...?

The TS typeof operator doesn't make things implicitly generic or dynamic. if key's type if keyof T then typeof key is also just keyof T, so value is of type T[keyof T] and is the union of all value types, unrelated to key. If you want your desired behavior you need to make [key, value] a discriminated union of tuple types as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?
